# SetInterval unpredictable response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

This has taken all my mental power so please kindly help me here.

```
this.pingInterval = window.setInterval(
   () => {
     checkMultivac() // an api call
  },
  20 * 1 * 1000,
  TIMER.PING_30_MIN,
);
```

And **checkMultivac** is

```
export const checkMultivac = async () => {
  // After successful payment, vend
  try {
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/api/checkVMC`;

    const response = await axios({
      url,
      method: 'GET',
      timeout: 1000 * 14,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      error: true,
      data: {},
    };
  }
};
```

The problem is it make multiple api calls. 
I Check it by opening network tab in chrome after 20 sec it send 2-4 api calls.

It was recommended to use settimeout instead but result are same in both cases. 
Any help please. 
Moreover i bind this function in **componentDidMount** (React) to my component.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of the third argument you're providing to `setInterval`? `setInterval` passes it to your callback, but your callback isn't using it...

Comment: Your problem is that you expect to see a call in every 20 seconds and your code make more calls than that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I use that to clear it later when I unmount that component

Comment: @Charlie the problem is after every 20 sec its making more than 2 api calls which is its callback fire more than once after 20 sec

Comment: Can you include an image of your network tab and highlight these 2-4 calls?

Comment: @Charlie adding

Comment: @Charlie done adding photos

Comment: Looks like they are preflight OPTIONS requests. See if the additional requests you see are of the verb OPTION

Answer (score 0):

Using `setInterval` for this will lead to chaos because your function is **asynchronous**. As far as the timer subsystem knows, the callback is complete as soon as your async function *starts* its work, it doesn't wait for it to finish.

To wait to finish, you need to use the promise that your function returns, and then start your next ping when it's done, something like this:

```
const schedulePing = () => {
    this.pingInterval = window.setTimeout( // <== `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`
       () => {
         checkMultivac()
         // Normally you'd need a `.catch(...)` call here to handle/report
         // errors, but you've ensured that `checkMultivac`
         // never rejects its promise, so...
         .finally(schedulePing);
      },
      20 * 1 * 1000      // <== `* 1` has no purpose here
      // TIMER.PING_30_MIN, <== Your code isn't using this
    );
};
schedulePing();
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    method() {
        const schedulePing = () => {
            log("Scheduling checkMultivac in 20s");
            this.pingInterval = window.setTimeout( // <== `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`
               () => {
                 checkMultivac()
                 // Normally you'd need a `.catch(...)` call here to handle/report
                 // errors, but you've ensured that `checkMultivac`
                 // never rejects its promise, so...
                 .finally(schedulePing);
              },
              20 * 1 * 1000      // <== `* 1` has no purpose here
              // TIMER.PING_30_MIN, <== Your code isn't using this
            );
        };
        schedulePing();
    }
};

function delay(ms, ...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args);
    });
}

async function checkMultivac() {
    log("checkMultivac start");
    await delay(Math.random() * 3000);
    log("checkMultivac end");
}

function log(...msgs) {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString().substring(11), ...msgs);
}

obj.method();
```

Note that that will start the next delay from the *end* of the previous call, so for instance if the call takes two seconds, with the above you'll have a 20s delay, then two seconds for the call, then a new 20s delay, etc. If you want to include those two seconds in the delay, it's a bit more complicated:

```
let lastStart = Date.now();
const schedulePing = () => {
    this.pingInterval = window.setTimeout( // <== `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`
        () => {
        lastStart = Date.now();
         checkMultivac()
         // Normally you'd need a `.catch(...)` call here to handle/report
         // errors, but you've ensured that `checkMultivac`
         // never rejects its promise, so...
         .finally(schedulePing);
      },
      Math.max(0, 20 * 1000 - (Date.now() - lastStart))
      // TIMER.PING_30_MIN, <== Your code isn't using this
    );
};
schedulePing();
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    method() {
        let lastStart = Date.now();
        const schedulePing = () => {
            let delay = Math.max(0, 20 * 1000 - (Date.now() - lastStart));
            log(`Scheduling checkMultivac in ${delay/1000}s`);
            this.pingInterval = window.setTimeout( // <== `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`
                () => {
                lastStart = Date.now();
                 checkMultivac()
                 // Normally you'd need a `.catch(...)` call here to handle/report
                 // errors, but you've ensured that `checkMultivac`
                 // never rejects its promise, so...
                 .finally(schedulePing);
              },
              delay
              // TIMER.PING_30_MIN, <== Your code isn't using this
            );
        };
        schedulePing();
    }
};

function delay(ms, ...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args);
    });
}

async function checkMultivac() {
    log("checkMultivac start");
    await delay(Math.random() * 3000);
    log("checkMultivac end");
}

function log(...msgs) {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString().substring(11), ...msgs);
}

obj.method();
```

Comment: Thanku. Checking and will response soon

Comment: It did not work. I also try making `window.pingInterval = ...` in case if its init multiple time. But same results

Comment: @RajanLagah - The first version above works just fine, see the live example. The second had a minor error (I did say it was off-the-cuff and would need checking) which I've fixed above, see the live example.